# Time Series Stationarity and Histograms

Tags: time-series, stationarity

In a paper I am reading, the author discusses stationarity and plots the histogram of returns for the time series he is studying. I was wondering if there was any relationship between stationarity of a time series and the density of the returns? For example, if the density is normal, is this more likely to imply stationarity?

The paper: http://dept.econ.yorku.ca/~jasiakj/papers/ANCHR.pdf

Comment: Well, by definition, for a nonstationary series, some features of the distribution are likely to change, so it does not make sense to show one view of an underlying density, unless appropriately defined, as here: http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/P/cd/d11b/d1181.pdf.

Comment: @fgnu so any ideas as to why the author discusses the issues together?